# SUMIFS Function Returning Value of First Occurrence Only Instead of Summing All

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am facing an unusual issue with the `SUMIFS()` function in Excel. I am attempting to sum values from a column based on a specific date criterion. The formula is structured to sum values from a dynamic array on another sheet (Sheet6). Here is the formula I am using:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet6!$B$3#,,2),INDEX(Sheet6!$B$3#,,3),[@Date])
```

The second column of the dynamic array holds the expected pay amount, and the third column holds the expected pay date.

**Expected Behavior:**
The formula should sum all the values from the dynamic array where the expected pay date matches the specified date.

**Actual Behavior:**
The formula only returns the value of the first occurrence that meets the date criterion, instead of summing all the occurrences.

**Steps Tried to Resolve:**

Verified data types and formatting for consistency.
Tested the formula with direct range references instead of using `INDEX()`:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet6!$C$3:$C$4000, Sheet6!$D$3:$D$4000, [@Date])
```

Tried using `SUMPRODUCT()` as an alternative:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet6!$C$3:$C$4000) * (Sheet6!$D$3:$D$4000 = [@Date]))
```

Attempted an array formula using `SUM()` and `IF()`:

```
=SUM(IF(Sheet6!$D$3:$D$4000 = [@Date], Sheet6!$C$3:$C$4000, 0))
```

Utilized `FILTER()` and `SUM()` combination:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Sheet6!$C$3:$C$4000, Sheet6!$D$3:$D$4000 = [@Date]))
```

All these attempts resulted in either an incorrect sum (first occurrence only) or a `#N/A` error indicating "A value is not available to the formula or function."

I've also used `COUNTIF()` to verify the number of occurrences of the specified date, and it returns the correct count, indicating multiple matching rows.

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet6!$D$3:$D$4000, [@Date])
```

I'm at a loss as to why `SUMIFS()` is not functioning as expected. Any insights or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would help to see sample data.

Comment: Possibly your dates include times but the formatting is hiding them.

Comment: You might have switched the ranges e.g. the same using `SUMIF` would look like this. `=SUMIF(INDEX(Sheet6!$B$3#,,3),[@Date],INDEX(Sheet6!$B$3#,,2))`. To make it spill in the table, clear the column before entering the formula into the first cell.

Comment: I tried to create some random data to try some formulas you mention and, I am not usually use and the funny part it not work for me, what i need to say be sure of arguments arrangement because its switched between "SUMIF" and "SUMIFS" also COUNTIF and COUNTIFS, also there is an other formula you not tried yet but all equals by the way ```=SUM($C$3:$C$4000*(($D$3:$D$4000)=[@Date]))``` notice to press ALT+SHIFT+ENTER as array function

Answer (score 0):

As @RonRosenFeld stated the problem was because I was averaging dates.  The average of a date became a decimal (That was interpreted by Excel as time).

Many thanks for your help all!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not just dates. SUMIF only sums the first column even if you ask it to sum a range.
I've listed a simple solution, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78209225/4476126